# Is there a way to open a context menu on a listview, anywhere but on the items in the listview using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Ive got a context menu that opens when you click on a specific item on the listview.

However I'd like a separate menu to open up when you right click on anywhere but the items on the listview box.

Could somebody please help me out? I'm sorry if the answers super obvious or this is a duplicate, but ive spent hours searching for an answer and have little idea about what im doing.

Comment: Please add a tag to indicate whether you are talking about WinForms or WPF ListView.

Comment: @elgonzo Sorry! Changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ListView's hit test helper.  The `ListViewHitTestInfo` object you get back will contain an `Item` member that you can test.  If that `Item` is `null`, that tells you that the right-click occurred on a non-item space in the control.

```
public void OnMouseUp(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        ListViewHitTestInfo htInfo = listView1.HitTest(e.Location);
        if (htInfo.Item != null)
            //display your menu
    }
}
```